# Cannot start appium node server

Tags: android, appium

I am new to Appium. I am not able to start Appium node server due to the following error

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   error: Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested port is already in use. Please make sure there's no other instance of Appium running already.
>
> Appium server process ended

The solution i found on stackoverflow , (kill node.exe from task manager) doesn't work for me as i did not find any node.exe there.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: After killing node.exe, are u getting same error or different one?

Comment: same error, actually i coudn't find any node.exe under processes in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you that the (TCP) port (4723) already has some process listening on it.  It is not possible to have more than one process listening on a given port at the same time.  You need to find what process is listening on that port and terminate it, or choose a different port for your appium server.

How you find it will be a bit different for you since you are on Windows.  (I use the shell command `netstat -anp | fgrep 4723`)

Comment: @Prasan this will help you to kill port .http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2015/04/16/windows-kill-process-by-port-number

Comment: @arulchristopher i tried this and getting ERROR: The process "11996" not found. where 11996 is the PID of port 4723

Comment: @Prasan https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2798040/you-cannot-stop-a-process-by-using-the-taskkill.exe-utility-in-windows could you check this to ensure  OS has fix for taskkill...

Comment: @arulchristopher Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as i am on windows 10.

Comment: Ensure you are running command prompt with Administrator privileges...... Still not working.... Sorry, Pls restart you system..

Comment: I am running command promt with Administrator privileges , it doesn't work. Restarting the system does work, but each time i have to restart in order to run my tests.

Comment: taskkill /F /T /PID  <pid> .  try  this command.   /T is for killing child process also.

Answer (score 0):

Use session override flag when starting Appium, so that you don't need to kill the process every time. Sample command -

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override
```